# Can I set ReSharper's TestRunner to tell me what line failed in my test?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

When I run my unit tests in ReSharper's TestRunner, they only tell me the failure that happened, not where in the test!  It even truncates a large part of the error message sometimes (because it does not fit on the screen).  To work around this, I need to run the test that failed in debug mode and it will stop on the failed line, but this take far more time.

Is there any way to just enable a line number output and full error messages?

Comment: For NUnit, you can always provide a custom error message for each test line. Read about the overloading methods, such as `Assert.AreEqual(object, object, string)`. That makes it easy to identify which line fails even if you have many test assertions in one test case.

Comment: I use resharper with nunit and get a full stack dump with a clickable link to the failure.

Comment: @adrianm How do you run your tests?  I run mine by clicking Ctrl-U, Ctrl-R which opens the test runner and runs the tests.

Comment: @adrianm You mean *Ctrl+R, Ctrl+U* for running current Unit Test Session.?

Comment: I don't have these key bindings but the window's name is Unit Test Session and it got an "output" pane where the stack dump is displayed

Comment: Sorry, I guess *Ctrl+R, Ctrl+U* is not a default shortcut. I had manually created that shortcut to the right command.

Comment: @just.another.programmer The output pane has a horizontal scrollbar that can be used to see full error message. (I have ReSharper 5.1.3.) I wished there were a word wrap option to show long error messages without using scrollbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you activate the **output pane** in ReSharper's *Unit Test Sessions* window?

Then you can **click on your test** and output pane shows all the errors and outputs (from `Console.Out.Write(...)`). There is usually a stack trace where you can click on a line to navigate to code.

Comment: I had the output pane minimized in my config and did not even realize it was there!

Comment: More on the [output pane here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Windows__Unit_Test_Sessions.html)